# Problems with installing packages to R

Tags: r

I tried this:

```
z <- zscore(NMEBXTP_MeanDepth, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and got this:

```
Error: could not find function "zscore"
```

So I did this:

```
install.packages(c("R.basic"), contriburl="http://www.braju.com/R/repos/")
```

And got this:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.braju.com/R/repos/
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘R.basic’ is not available
```

Besides being dysbinarylexic whats my problem?

Comment: What version of R have you got? Maybe the one on that repository needs a newer R version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you load the package for use before trying to use it? You need

```
library("R.basic")
```

or

```
require("R.basic")
```

to actually load the package functions into the running R session for you to be able to use them.

If you don't actually have it installed at all, then something looks amiss with the repository. If we look [here](http://www.braju.com/R/) we see that **R.basic** has been deprecated and is not on CRAN. Further, [the page tells](http://www.braju.com/R/) us that many of the **R.basic** are in the **R.utils** and **aroma.light** packages, both of which are on CRAN. Take a look at the CRAN pages for **[R.utils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html)** and **[aroma.light](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aroma.light/index.html)** to see which one you need for the functionality you wanted to use.

If the problem installing from that repository continues, contact the maintainer of the repository to report the problem.

Comment: Thanx. This is too much for me. Hopefully this will help someone else. I solved it the old school way: z <- (vector-mean(vector))/sd(vector)

Comment: @AxelWilhelmEinarsson Err, why not `scale()` that comes with every copy of R without needing to load anything?!